# Summing up GROUP BY results

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm learning SQL using this Oracle database.

[image: diagram]

I ran into some problems with the task: display the number of all employees and the number of people hired in 2004, 2005, 2006 year after year.

I can do these two parts separately but the teacher said it has to be handled within one query and no subqueries are needed.

```
SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

The above line counts all employees.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) AS YEAR, COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) AS HIRED_EMPLOYEES 
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) IN (2004, 2005, 2006) 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE);
```

And the above part works fine for counting people hired in 2004, 2005, 2006.

I think maybe there's a way to sum my results grouped by year and get the overall number of employees within this single query but the WHERE part is the obstacle. I'd appreciate any suggetions, probably as simple as possible as it was only my second class of writing queries.

Comment: `UNION` both queries? Sneaky trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the yearly total -Note this is total employees ever - If you only want Count for the 3 years then add your WHERE Clause back in.

```
SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) AS HIRED_EMPLOYEES ,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) AS YEAR = 2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [2016 Hire Count],
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) AS YEAR = 2017 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [2017 Hire Count],
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) AS YEAR = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as [2018 Hire Count]
FROM EMPLOYEES ;
```

Comment: Exactly what I came to. +1

Comment: Just a note. There's no need for `ELSE` since in SQL the default value is `NULL` and `SUM()` ignores it.

Comment: So this actually counts the number of rows with year values 2016, 2017, 2018 separately, could you explain what the "1 else 0" part does?

Comment: Hi Theta - This is a quick way of counting the rows that match the criteria. EG - If you imagine each row will have a hire date and if that is the right year then a 1 is set otherwise a 0- than all these 1s and 0s are added together.

Comment: @johnMcTighe A really nice explanation and a trick I'll surely use, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
with
x as (
  select extract(year from hire_date) as year from employees
)
select
  count(*) as total,
  sum(case when year = 2004 then 1 end) as hired_2004,
  sum(case when year = 2005 then 1 end) as hired_2005,
  sum(case when year = 2006 then 1 end) as hired_2006
from x
```